# PHP. Как передать функции другую функцию в качестве аргумента

Tags: php, javascript, функции

Как передать функции другую функцию в качестве аргумента в php?

Знаю, в js можно сделать так:

```
 exampleFunction(function(){

 }, nameFunction);
```

Как можно реализовать такое на php, знак $ мешает =)

Comment: В php я новичок)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function test($callback) {
    $callback();
}

test(function() {
    echo 'callback';
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, чет я туплю не много.